# How to interpret this relationship between coefficients in linear regression?

Tags: statistics, least-squares, hypothesis-testing, linear-regression

we are having the following problem:

Suppose a linear regression model with the following form

$$ Y = B_0 + B_1 X_1 + B_2 X_2 + e$$

if we run the regression (with OLS) we end up with the following results

| $$X_i$$ | Estimation $$(B_i)$$ | Standard deviation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.85*** | (0.12) |
| 2 | 0.82*** | (0.26) |

where *** means p-value<0,001

The question that we are having with our team is the next:

Can we say this? $$B_1 > B_2$$

Since $$.85 > .82$$

or do we have to take into consideration the standard deviation? reason for which we couldn't assume the previous result.

The possible answer that we are thinking of are:

1. With the evidence we can't say that B1>B2 since if we have into account the standard deviation the CI overlaps
2. We can say that, on average, B1>B2, but is not statistically significant
3. On average, B1>B2
4. Other option/procedures...

Thank you in advance, if it is possible, it would help any paper that justifies the answer

Comment: I'm not an expert in this type of analysis. But I would assume the answer is no for every option you suggest.

1. Even if the CIs did not overlap, that would not guarantee your inequality. It would only give evidence towards the claim.

2. I don't even know what this means... $B_1$ is an unknown parameter, which is approximated by using linear regression. So I would say that $B_1$ and $B_2$ have a definitive inequality, but you cannot say what it is. And on average does not mean anything because it has a value.

3. Same deal.

4. Not really sure, but maybe someone has a good idea.